# Serilog places logfile in solution

Tags: asp.net-core, serilog

I have a netcore webapp and im trying to use serilog for logging. I have the simplest possible setup.

```
    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .Enrich.FromLogContext()
        .WriteTo.Debug()
        .WriteTo.File("log.txt", rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day)
        .CreateLogger();
```

and in Hostbuilder

```
.ConfigureLogging(log =>
     {
         log.ClearProviders();
         log.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Information);
         log.AddSerilog();
      })
```

When running in debug mode this places a log20210326.txt straight into my solution. I get that it needs to go somewhere in debug, but it should be in bin/debug or somewhere in the local IIS. I could swear it used to work this way.

How do i get it to stop?

Answer (score 4):

Serilog.Sinks.File writes to the folder set as the "working directory". ASP.NET sets the project directory as the "working directory" to avoid copying a significant number of content files to the output directory during build which would degrade the dev "inner loop" experience.

If you want the log file to be written to the `bin\Debug` folder, just tell Serilog to write the file to [`AppContext.BaseDirectory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appcontext.basedirectory?view=net-5.0).

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
    .WriteTo.Debug()
    .WriteTo.File(Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, "log.txt"),
        rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day)
    .CreateLogger();
```

---

ps: It's a good practice to call `Log.CloseAndFlush()` before your application ends, to make sure all the writes are flushed through the sinks and, in your case, to make sure the file is closed (instead of being locked by IIS Express).

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            .WriteTo.Debug()
            .WriteTo.File(Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, "log.txt"),
                rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day)
            .CreateLogger();

        try
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }
        finally
        {
            Log.CloseAndFlush(); // <<#<<#<<#<<#
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How can we set the application base path when we use `var logger = new LoggerConfiguration().ReadFrom.Configuration(config).CreateLogger();`? Note: in config, we cannot able to set the base path.